# PhoneGap, JQueryMobile JSON and springMVC

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have developed web architectures using Spring and now i want to do smart phone applications using phoneGap and JQueryMobile so my question is if its smart connect that frontend to a springmvc backend using json.

Im new with jquerymobile and json if you could provide me some tutorials or give me a hint that will be great!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jQuery-Mobile, the [demos](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/) are the most recommended.

For PhoneGap, [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-development/) is a small introduction tutorial and you may also need the [API documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/index.html). [Tutorials in PhoneGap website](http://phonegap.com/start) are also very useful.

And about the architecture, with a Spring-based backend, I have used it before and I can tell you it works quite well.

Comment: what do you think is better doing the apps with phonegap and jquery or programing them native?, The apps are spected to be really simple.

Comment: The question is whether you plan to develop applications for different platforms. In this case I really recommend you using a framework such as PhoneGap, or maybe you can also check Ruby-based [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/).

Comment: Yes, Im planning to use phonegap but having a backend with spring mvc also Ill try to use javapns for sending notifications. What do you think about this architecture?

Comment: I don't know about JavaPNS, sorry, but using Spring in the backend seems a good idea for me.